# AG Grid angular show hide buttons based on row clicked

Tags: angular, ag-grid, togglebutton, ag-grid-angular

In AG Grid angular, in a column, I have a button called <kbd>Edit</kbd>, and when I click on that, it should hide and show the other two buttons — <kbd>update</kbd> and <kbd>cancel</kbd> — in the same cell. It is working fine but when we have <kbd>update</kbd> and <kbd>cancel</kbd> buttons open in one row, if we click on other rows' <kbd>Edit</kbd> button, the previous row <kbd>update</kbd> and <kbd>cancel</kbd> has to hide and current row <kbd>update</kbd> and <kbd>cancel</kbd> should popup.

Now it is shown like this:

[image]

...but I would like it to show like this:

[image]

AG Grid component.ts

```
  columnDef=[ 
        //other columns.....
     {
         field: 'Actions',
         cellRenderer: PrepostButtonsComponent,
         cellRendererParams: {
         onClick: (rowData: any) => this.onEdit(rowData),
         onUpdate: (rowData: any) => this.onUpdate(rowData),
         onCancel: (rowData: any) => this.onCancel(rowData),
        },
       }
    ] 

    onEdit(event:any){
        //code block
     }
     //for other two buttons also same
```

buttonRender.html

```
     <div *ngIf="!isEdit">
     <button type='button' class="btn-edit" (click)="onEdit()" >Edit </button>
     </div>
     <div class="btns-grid" *ngIf="isEdit">
      <button type='button' class="btn-edit" (click)='onUpdate()' >Update </button>
      <button type='button' class="btn-cancel" (click)='onCancel()' >Cancel </button>
     </div>
```

buttonRender.ts

```
    isEdit:false;
    params;
    label: string;
    rowData:any

   agInit(params): void {
      this.params = params;
      this.label = this.params.label || null;
         }

    refresh(params?: any): boolean {
     return true;
     }

      ngOnInit(): void{     }
    onEdit() {
       isEdit = true;
       this.params.onClick(this.params.node.data);
        }

     onUpdate() {
       isEdit = false;
       this.params.onUpdate(this.params.node.data);
      }
     onCancel() {
      isEdit = false;
      this.params.onCancel(this.params.node.data);
      }
```

Comment: If your edit/update/cancel buttons (Along with other data) are rendered inside a ngFor, you can make the code much compact passing the index to edit method to handle buttons on that specific element under ngFor. So for example on `onEdit(index)` you can close all other update/cancel buttons and display theri edit buttons, and then hide this particular edit at 'index' and display its upload/cancel or toggle the other way around.